# Count of $N$ digit numbers with no repeating neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many $N$ digit numbers are there such that neighboring digits are distinct and first and last digits are distinct too.

For $2$ digits there are $9\cdot 9$ obviously.

For $3$ digits it's $9\cdot 8\cdot 8+9\cdot 1\cdot 9$.

Same logic I can apply for $4$ and $5$ digits but the number of terms grows and it becomes hard to keep track. 
So how to proceed?

Comment: Why the split up $9\times8\times8+9\times1\times9$ by $3$ digits? It seems to me that there are $9\times9$ possibilities for (D1,D2). If both are placed then there are $8$ possibilities for D3. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: For 5 Digit I have the answer , 53136

Comment: I have calculated it using a code which counted one by one. So you can match your logic with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's *not* exclude that the first digit takes value $0$.

(Excluding afterwards that the first digit takes value $0$ means that the outcome must be mupltiplied with $0.9$)

Let $A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}^N$

For $i=1,\dots,N-1$ let $A_i=\{d\in A\mid d_i=d_{i+1}\}$

Let $A_N=\{d\in A\mid d_N=d_1\}$.

To be found is then $|A-A_1\cup\dots\cup A_N|=10^N-|A_1\cup\dots\cup A_N|$

Here $|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_N|$ can be found by [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) applying that $|A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}|=10^{N-k}$ whenever $1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\leq N$ and $k<N$ together with $|A_1\cap\dots\cap A_N|=10$.

This leads to:$$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\binom{N}i(-1)^i10^{N-i}+(-1)^N10=\sum_{i=0}^{N}\binom{N}i(-1)^i10^{N-i}-(-1)^N+(-1)^N10=$$$$9^N+9(-1)^N$$

So the final outcome ($0$ excluded as first digid) is:$$\frac9{10}\left(9^N+9(-1)^N\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

A start for you:

There are $9$ digits you can place in the "first" position.  To the right you can place just $8$ (the ones that are different from the first position).  Next to the right you can place just $8$ (the ones that are different from the second position).  And so on.  At position $n-2$ either you have the SAME digit as the first position (in which case you have $8$ possibilities for position $n-1$, or instead you have a DIFFERENT digit as the first position (in which case you have just $7$ possibilities for position $n-1$.

Comment: In the second position there are 9 possible digits, 0 included

Comment: @R0xx0rZzz:  No.  If the $n=2$ case has $9 \times 9$ possibilities (as you write), that means that the digit $0$ (or some other one) is excluded.  For the $n=2$ case with ten digits ($0\ldots 9$), there are $10 \times 9$ cases.  So your question implies just $1 \ldots 9$ are available.

Comment: No 0 is excluded only from the first digit , cause if first is 0 the number is no more n digit but rather n-1

Answer (score 0):

Since a leading zero apparently isn't allowed (except perhaps for a one-digit number), let's see. The initial exhaustively-counted results are:

$$ 10, 81, 648, 5913, 53136, 478305, 4304664, 38742057… $$

According to prime factorization and a bit of pattern finding, this corresponds to the following:

$$ \begin{align}
     10 &= 9 + 1
\\   81 &= 9 \times 9
\\   648 &= 8 \times 9 \times 9
\\   5913 &= (8 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9
\\   53136 &= (9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 \times 9
\\   478305 &= ((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9
\\   4304664 &= ((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 \times 9
\\   38742057 &= (((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9
   \end{align}
$$

My guesses for the next values:

$$
    (((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 \times 9
\\  ((((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9
\\  ((((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 \times 9
\\  (((((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9
\\  \vdots
$$

Note the two-stage pattern, repeating with yet another $ (9 \times 9 + 1) $ nested at the beginning:

1. $ (\cdots((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \cdots \times 8 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 $
2. $ (\cdots((9 \times 9 + 1) \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \cdots \times 9 \times 9 + 1) \times 8 \times 9 \times 9 $

Comment: Alright but what about the logic?

Comment: I've added the pattern that I see, which would need to be checked.

Comment: Solution is one thing but understanding is other. I want to understand the problem and solution